# Decode an encoded value from DB using Python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I encoded a value from input file and inserted into Sqlite DB

```
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Locations (address, geodata)
            VALUES ( ?, ? )''', (memoryview(address.encode()), memoryview(data.encode()) ) )
```

Now I'm trying to decode it but I'm getting

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "return.py", line 9, in 
print(c.decode('utf-8'))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode'

My code looks like this:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('geodata.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('SELECT address FROM Locations')

for c in cur:
    print(c.decode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how many columns are selected, rows are returned as tuples. You would get the first element of the tuple the usual way.